# Why is Delete Highlighted button on Attribute Table grayed out in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, editing, delete

I have a few thousand points of data in one layer in ArcMap. I'm editing those points through the Attribute table and now have the data that I don't want displayed highlighted in the table. About 3.5 thousand of 5 thousand points. However, I can't delete it due to the "Delete Selected" and "Delete Highlighted" being grayed out and I'm not quite sure why or what my options are to filter this data.

Deleting these highlighted lines deletes the actual point on the graph correct?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the format of the point source (and if Enterprise geodatabase, which RDBMS release is in use), and whether you have an open edit session associated to the data workspace. Do you want the Delete the features or just to Unselect them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will delete the points in the layer. Make sure you check you are in Editor mode when the points are highlighted. You can only delete points in Editor mode.

Here is the documentation on how to start an edit session: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/starting-an-edit-session.htm

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in a versioned environment? If so, and recent changes were made to a dataset and it was not registered as versioned, this would make the data unavailable to edit (delete) until this was done and therefore greying out the delete button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).